# Docker mount host directory not container when using Docker inside Docker by docker.sock

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using Docker inside docker by mount docker.sock into container for Jenkins docker agents. In my Jenkins container, when I execute

```
docker run -t -d -v /var/data:/var:data image_name
```

it will not create and mount /var/data folder inside Jenkins container. Instead it create a folder in my host and mounted into agent container.

Does this behavior expected?

Comment: Yes, the left-hand side of a `docker run -v` option is always a physical path on the host, even if `docker run` is being launched from another container.

Comment: Note that if you use the [Jenkins Docker integration](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) and run pipeline commands `image.inside { ... }`, it knows how to mount the current `WORKDIR`, and that Docker named volumes don't have this problem.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you David